# SVG does not fit on Iphone - (.htaccess is the problem)

Tags: ios, .htaccess, svg, mobile, viewbox

I am getting crazy with the animated SVG of my website ( https://finbizimpactinvesting.com ). On the desktop it works well and the SVG fits in the middle of the monitor (chrome, safari, mac, windows all the combination) as well as android devices, but on Iphone mobile devices it does not fit whatever the browser it is.

I tried to play with the viewBox but it is almost impossible to make it fit on different devices with the same output.

```
<div class = "logo">

          <svg version="1.1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
              <circle class="r" cx="41%" cy="41%" r="8" ></circle>
              <circle class="r" cx="59%" cy="41%" r="8" ></circle>
              <circle class="r" cx="41%" cy="59%" r="8" ></circle>
              <circle class="r" cx="59%" cy="59%" r="8" ></circle></svg>
                      </div>
```

```
.logo {
   position: absolute;
  top: -150px;
  z-index: -1;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 1225px;
  height: 250px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.logo svg {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: -150px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  fill: transparent;
  overflow: overlay;
}

.r {
  opacity: 0;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-dasharray: 130;
  -webkit-animation-name: vladi;
       -o-animation-name: vladi;
          animation-name: vladi;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
       -o-animation-duration: 3s;
          animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
       -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
          animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
       -o-animation-direction: alternate;
          animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
       -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
          animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
       -o-transform-origin: center center;
          transform-origin: center center;
}


@keyframes vladi {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 130;
    stroke: #000000;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  60% {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke: #000000;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  70% {
    fill: #000000;
  }

  91% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
         -o-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  92% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
         -o-transform: scale(0.9);
            transform: scale(0.9);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
         -o-transform: scale(2);
            transform: scale(2);
    fill: #000000;
  }
}
```

Many Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem!! the issue is the .htaccess file that i am using to force the http into htpps. I don't know why but with it the Svg does not work and without it the SVG works great.